# My score counter is being inconsistent for a dice game

Tags: javascript, counter, dice

I'm just starting to learn JavaScript (with HTML), and so I'm trying to make a Dice Game from the course I'm doing. The two functions, `ranGen1` and `ranGen2` basically just generate a random number (1-6) and shows a new image for the dice to fit that.

What I'm trying to do with this `scoreCounter`, is to compare `ranGen1` and `ranGen2` and whichever has a higher dice roll wins and adds 1 to the score on its side.

```
var scorePlayer1 = 0;
var scorePlayer2 = 0;

function scoreCounter(){
    ranGen1();
    ranGen2();
    if (ranGen1() > ranGen2()){
        scorePlayer1++;
        document.querySelector(".scoreCounter1").textContent = scorePlayer1;
    }
    else if (ranGen2() > ranGen1()){
        scorePlayer2++;
        document.querySelector(".scoreCounter2").textContent = scorePlayer2;
    }
}
```

Everything is working as it should be - the dice is producing a new image when I click the button, the points are being written in the right place (`scoreCounter1` and `scoreCounter2` - sorry for the naming, I'm not gonna bother coming up with something else right now), except the `scoreCounter` function is super inconsistent.

Often, when `ranGen1` is bigger or equal, it gives the point to `ranGen2` and vice versa. And many times, it just doesn't give the points to either side.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the issue is that you are encountering, but I will point out that you should have the score counter elements stored outside the function for performance issues

Comment: scorePlayer1 and scorePlayer2 are the score counters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The two functions, ranGen1 and ranGen2 basically just generate a random number (1-6)" So, think carefully about the logic. In the code shown, how many times do these functions get called? Will they return the same value every time, or possibly different numbers on occasion (hint: what is the purpose, again?) Therefore, when the code says `ranGen1() > ranGen2()`, and then says `ranGen2() > ranGen1()`, can you see why the results of the comparison would not be consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `RanGen1()` and `RanGen2()` multiple times, and they return different random numbers each time. So the results of the comparisons will change.

You should just call them once, save the results in variables, and compare these.

```js
function scoreCounter() {
  let r1 = ranGen1();
  let r2 = ranGen2();
  if (r1 > r2) {
    scorePlayer1++;
    document.querySelector(".scoreCounter1").textContent = scorePlayer1;
  } else if (r2 > r1) {
    scorePlayer2++;
    document.querySelector(".scoreCounter2").textContent = scorePlayer2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe these aren't the only bugs.